# I wrote the following code to insert data in asp.net using c#. But i find error in the code. can you please help me with it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
protected void btnAuctionInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Database connection
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=Reshani;Initial Catalog=JKPLC;Integrated Security=True");

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        //insert function

        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT into [Auction_Details] (year,sale_no,sale_Date,lot_no,quantity_sold,value,buyer_name,sample_id,broker_id) VALUES(@year,@sale_no,@Sale_date,@lot_no,@lot_no_quantity,@value,'@buyer_name',null,null)";

        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("homeforStaff.aspx.cs");
        sqlConnection1.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error :" + ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where you are adding the parameters to command object? An why you have quotes `'@buyer_name'` here?

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem is that you do not assign any `SqlParameter` to your command. It is not enough to simply use `@something` in the string. But that is not the only problem. See my edits to your code below, carefully read the comments:

```
protected void btnAuctionInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Put Disposable resources in "using" blocks to automatically handle clean up.
        //Assign connection to command in the constructor
        using(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=Reshani;Initial Catalog=JKPLC;Integrated Security=True"))
        using(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlConnection1))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            //Do not use any quotes around parameters.
            cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT into [Auction_Details] (year,sale_no,sale_Date,lot_no,quantity_sold,value,buyer_name,sample_id,broker_id) VALUES(@year,@sale_no,@Sale_date,@lot_no,@lot_no_quantity,@value,@buyer_name,null,null)";

            //Create parameters
            //SqlDbType is assumed, only you know what data type your parameters are so alter accordingly
            SqlParameter p_year = new SqlParameter("@year", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
            //Set parameter value. Only you know where this value comes from. You can't run the INSERT without assigning values to parameters.
            p_year.Value = 2000;
            //Add eaach parameter to the command
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_year);

            //Add the other 6 parameters here.....

            sqlConnection1.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //the proper way to Redirect in Asp.Net
            //You do not redirect to .cs files, you request .aspx
            Response.Redirect("homeforStaff.aspx", false);
            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Exception objects have a reasonably good ToString override
        //so make it easy on yourself and just use it.
        Response.Write("Error :" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ruwanika I'm not actually running your code, I'm just mocking it up. You will have to show the error you are getting. You may also want to add an update to your question with the code change and new problems to avoid making a mess in the comments.